# Why is EFCore generating a TempId-Column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a one-to-many relationship like this:

```
    [Table("Common_T229")]
public class OrderDetail {
    [Column("F229_ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ... more columns

    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetailTimeRange> TimeRanges { get; set; } = new Collection<OrderDetailTimeRange>();

}

    [Table("WP_OpPlanAuftragZeitrahmen")]
public class OrderDetailTimeRange {
    [Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ... more columns

    public OrderDetail OrderDetail { get; set; }
}


public class E3kDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
                    .HasMany(m => m.TimeRanges)
                    .WithOne(d => d.OrderDetail)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrderNumber)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    
    }
}
```

When I do this query

```
public IEnumerable<OrderDetailDto> SearchData() {
    var e3k = ContextProviderService.GetE3kContext();

    IQueryable<OrderDetail> query = e3k.OrderDetails.Include(x => x.TimeRanges);

    query = query.Take(5000);

    foreach (var data in query) {
         // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
fail: 05.06.2023 18:30:30.800 RelationalEventId.CommandError[20102] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
  Failed executing DbCommand (41ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT [t].[F229_ID], [t].[F229_70], [t].[F229_34], [t].[F229_36], [t].[F229_03], [t].[F229_02], [t].[F229_89], [t].[TempId], [w].[Id], [w].[Von], [w].[Feiertag], [w].[AnzahlMitarbeiter], [w].[AuftragsNr], [w].[Samstag], [w].[Sonntag], [w].[Zeit], [w].[Bis]
  FROM (
      SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [c].[F229_ID], [c].[F229_70], [c].[F229_34], [c].[F229_36], [c].[F229_03], [c].[F229_02], [c].[F229_89], [c].[TempId]
      FROM [Common_T229] AS [c]
  ) AS [t]
  LEFT JOIN [WP_OpPlanAuftragZeitrahmen] AS [w] ON [t].[TempId] = [w].[AuftragsNr]
  ORDER BY [t].[F229_ID]
dbug: 05.06.2023 18:30:30.802 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosing[20002] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
      Closing connection to database 'Dev_e3k_DietscheV6' on server '62.2.129.5\SQL2017,1433'.
dbug: 05.06.2023 18:30:30.805 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosed[20003] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
      Closed connection to database 'Dev_e3k_DietscheV6' on server '62.2.129.5\SQL2017,1433' (2ms).
fail: 05.06.2023 18:30:30.820 CoreEventId.QueryIterationFailed[10100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query)
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Dik.WebApp.DataAccess.E3kDbContext'.
      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'TempId'.
```

Why is EFCore generating a column TempId?

Comment: I tested your code , there was no problem, probably other layers or other Columns will add this code,can share other Column or explain your work

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem - perhaps it can help someone else:

OrderDetailTimeRange.OrderNumber is not navigating to the primarykey of OrderDetails. So I have to define the PrincipalKey in OnModelCreating for the One-to-Many-Relationship.